# How to display a views grid in a responsive (mobile friendly) grid layout?

Tags: views, 7, theming

I have a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) grid format, with 3 columns. I want to see the columns in cascade on mobile devices.

Any suggestions how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid) module. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides a views plugin for displaying content in a responsive (mobile friendly) grid layout. Rather than trying to force the standard Views grid display to work for mobile this provides the same functionality, but in DIVs instead of tables. Provided is also the ability to specify a horizontal or vertical grid layout which will properly stack the content on a mobile display.
>
> Features:
>
> - Horizontal or vertical grid layouts
> - Custom classes for use with responsive themes

**Note**: available for D7 only (not for D6). This is what the project page states regarding D8:

> This module will not be ported for Drupal 8. Views grids in core have been replaced with DIVs ([#1903746: Replace the views grid table template with one using divs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903746))!